# Is it bad practise to utilize many threads? (through SwingWorkers)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, garbage-collection, swingworker

My Java (Swing) application creates a new SwingWorker object when it needs to (e.g) download data from the Internet and do something at the same time (think display a loader). However, monitoring the threads created, this can quickly reach ~100 threads.

Is this bad practice? If yes; what's the proper way to do it? Doesn't the GC automatically clean up unused threads?

Comment: Is this in a Java Swing application? Are all 100 threads doing something?

Comment: @thatidiotguy Yes, a Java Swing application. They've been doing something, but they all complete quite quickly (up to 10 seconds, approximately). The amount of threads increase as the time goes and the user uses the application.

Comment: *"Doesn't the GC automatically clean up unused threads?"* If they terminate cleanly...

Comment: @MarcoForberg Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @Zar He's saying don't expect a thread that does `while(1){}` to be cleaned up by the GC

Comment: hard to tell whatever cleaver, by default SwingWorker isn't reusable, ended in done(), after this moment are every methods finalized, have to test, depends of variables hold returns from SwingWorker, every Java IDE has built_in JProfiler, there you can to see those Objects, GC'ed, in_memory, by type, sortable ...

Comment: GC has nothing to do with threads because the `Thread` object **is not a thread**, no more than a `File` object is a file.

Comment: Exactly. A Thread will use a native thread when running, but after finishing cleanly, the native thread is released and the java.lang.Thread object may be GC'd if it is in a state that allows this and when GC'ing occurs. Have you considered use of a fixed-size thread pool?

Comment: @Zar thatidiotguy (nothing personal ;) ) says exactly what i meant. So avoid infinite loops and use running flags instead

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a bad practice when you put no upper bound on the number of threads (or generally *resources*).

In this case you better use a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) which contains at most a specific number of threads (say for example 25). You can either create them all at startup, or create them lazily on demand.

Implement a simple request manager system for the pool, which gives to the requesters the resources (or in case of running out of resources, queues them or simply denies them).

In this way, cleaning them in the end will also be easy and obvious.